# c++ rand() % 100

Tags: c++, arrays, random, populate

im trying to fill an array with random 200 numbers that can very from 0-100. I get it populated except the last couple number are very odd.

here my code.

```
     for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LIST_ELEMENTS; i++)
 {
    int  j = rand() % 100;

     list[i] = j;

 }
```

my output comes out at follows

Original Arrays:

```
41  67  34   0  69  24  78  58  62  64   5  45  81  27  61  91  95  42  27  36  91   4   2  53  92  82  21  16  18
95  47  26  71  38  69  12  67  99  35  94   3  11  22  33  73  64  41  11  53  68  47  44  62  57  37  59  23  41
29  78  16  35  90  42  88   6  40  42  64  48  46   5  90  29  70  50   6   1  93  48  29  23  84  54  56  40  66
76  31   8  44  39  26  23  37  38  18  82  29  41  33  15  39  58   4  30  77   6  73  86  21  45  24  72  70  29
77  73  97  12  86  90  61  36  55  67  55  74  31  52  50  50  41  24  66  30   7  91   7  37  57  87  53  83  45
 9   9  58  21  88  22  46   6  30  13  68   0  91  62  55  10  59  24  37  48  83  95  41   2  50  91  36  74  20
96  21  48  99  68  84  81  34  53  99  18  38   0  88  27  67  28  93  48  83   7  21  10  17  13  14-858993460

 9  16  35  51   0  49  19  56  98   3  24   8  44   9  89   2  95  85  93  43  23  87  14   3  48   0  58  18  80
96  98  81  89  98   9  57  72  22  38  92  38  79  90  57  58  91  15  88  56  11   2  34  72  55  28  46  62  86
75  33  69  42  44  16  81  98  22  51  21  99  57  76  92  89  75  12   0  10   3  69  61  88   1  89  55  23   2
85  82  85  88  26  17  57  32  32  69  54  21  89  76  29  68  92  25  55  34  49  41  12  45  60  18  53  39  23
79  96  87  29  49  37  66  49  93  95  97  16  86   5  88  82  55  34  14   1  16  71  86  63  13  55  85  53  12
 8  32  45  13  56  21  58  46  82  81  44  96  22  29  61  35  50  73  66  44  59  92  39  53  24  54  10  45  49
86  13  74  22  68  18  87   5  58  91   2  25  77  14  14  24  34  74  72  59  33  70  87  97  18  77-33686019
```

notice that last number in each array is really weird. Is there anything I can do to avoid this? btw this is two different arrays.

**Thanks everyone that posted! I got it working!**

Comment: I think your array's size is greater then NUM_LIST_ELEMENTS by one

Comment: Are you sure your array bounds are correct? Try printing numbers out after the loop with for(int i = 0; i < NUM_LIST_ELEMENTS; i++) printf("%d ", list[i]);

Comment: You are printing something else after your last number. There isn't any space, between `14-858993460` and `77-33686019`.

Comment: Mod is a really undesirable way to fit rand values into a range.  Probably more than you want to know but look here: http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html    In addition to that, see the answers below about invalid array indexing.

Comment: The arrays you show each include 201 elements.  (Counting the last output as two separate numbers)

Comment: Show your complete code. No error in this code. And better to move declaration of variable j before loop

Comment: `std::generate(std::begin(list), std::end(list), []{return std::rand() % 100;});` - Reusing existing code is a good thing :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are reading one beyond the end of the array.

e.g. if you populate an array with 200 elements, you should write to and read from 0 to 199 not 0 to 200 or 1 to 200.

By the way - rand() % 100 will not make numbers from 0 to 100. It will make numbers from 0 to 99 only.

Also, as Randy Howard says (thanks), you can get a more even random generation by following the advice at http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html .

Comment: Did you count the amount of numbers in his output?

Comment: @André Puel Do I count 201?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because there is something wrong with your code that prints the result. You might be looping from index 0 to 200, which has 201 items.

I counted your outputs and found there is 201 items, if the last 77-33686019 are actually 2 separate numbers.

If it's not that, you might have some printf/cout somewhere further down your code that actually prints some other value. To confirm this you can probably try `printf ("\n");` right after your loop that outputs the array. If your negative number ends up on a different line, you'll know it's some other printf further down your code.

You might want to use `int  j = rand() % 101;` instead so that you get 0 to 100. Your original code gives you the random range from 0 to 99.